# what does space of all models means

Tags: machine-learning

In one of the Lectures taken at Wroclaw University of Technology, the instructor defines machine learning in three steps: -

1) Defines a space of all possible models

2) Learns the parameters and structure of models from data

3) make predictions and decisions

In my understanding,each set of values for the parameters would correspond to a separate model (as a result, a model space is created when we consider all sets of parameter values).

Further, the set of parameter values for which test accuracy is maximum is the best model.

Then what is being done in step (1) in the name of defining a space of all possible models

In particular, what does "space of models" means and how is it obtained

Answer (score 2):

The space of models is not obtained, it is set by the modeler. Think of two models: $$f_1(x|a,c)=ax+c$$ and $$f_2(x|a,c)=a\sin(x)+c$$
If you're looking for the best model among all models that are of one of these two forms, then that is your space. You always look for solutions on the class of models.